# Submitting game dashboard news items with C# SDK

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-c#-sdk, dashboard

I'm looking for samples/references to submitting dashboard news items. I see the REST API is getting deprecated, and after too many hours looking, I can't find any documentation on submitting game notifications ("You've been invited to a new game," "It's your turn," etc).

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like:

```
var fwc = new FacebookWebClient(AccessToken);

fwc.Post("me/apprequests", new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"message", MessageToSend }
});
```

The sort of game notifications that you are looking for sound like "App-generated Requests" (See "Notications" at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/). Following their link (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#requests), you'll see that there is an API called "apprequests" that you can call with a value of "message".

Note also that you should clean up these requests once the user acts on them by clicking / accepting the request back into your app.

Comment: Given the age of this, it's probably deprecated. If you downvote, why not sure the new answer when you find it?